# What are the stats for the DLC weapons?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider multiplayer, there are six DLC weapons that can be bought. They refer to Hitman: Absolution.

Tomb Raider: Hitman: Absolution Weapons Pack
Agency SPS 12 (shotgun)
HX AP-15 (rifle)
Silverballer (pistol)

Tomb Raider: Hitman: Absolution Weapons Pack 2
JAGD P22G (pistol)
M590 12ga (pump shotgun)
STG 58 Elite (rifle)

I don't know of a way to check their stats before purchase except by asking someone else who already has them. What are their stats (good resolution screenshots)? Is it also true that at least one of the weapons' sound is suppressed?

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous question to be more like this one?

Comment: (1) I thought that it was close enough. (2) I figured that trying to get a closed question re-opened is too much of a hassle.